# Is there a way in linux to determine the (active/idle) state of an external drive without hdparm?

Tags: linux

Is there a way in linux to determine the (active/idle) state of an external drive without `hdparm`?
Cause `hdparm` commands are not compatible with the chip of my external case.
I use `hd-idle` to spindown, but sometimes the disk won't spin down and therefore i would like to check that (without waking it up - of course).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us some more detail about your hardware setup. What is the machine you are using and what is the external case? What is the external drive? And what Linux distribution are you using?